# Unable to label bar graph axes properly?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having this issue of labeling my axes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={0.4894, 0.4920, 0.4907, 1.4872, 1.4886},
        xtick=data
      ylabel={Mean Coefficient of Friction},
      xlabel= {Cart Mass (kg)},
        ]
                \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
            (0.4894,   0.005274)
            (0.4920,  0.005250)
            (0.4907, 0.005201)
            (1.4872, 0.0052144)
            (1.4886, 0.0052233)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Syntax error: There's a comma missing after `xtick=data`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its fixed by a minor syntax error nor really related to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working fine you just need to add `,` after `data` as **@jarauh** mentioned.

[image]